# NEW DISK ELEMENTARY OS

Tags: disk-management, disk

how to add a new disk to an existing elementary os system?

the second question is this:

Once I add this new disk, how can I install Steam on it? Can I just put Steam into the main Elementary OS drive and select game installations on the newly added one?